# PyPDFLoader spanish special characters

Tags: pypdf

When loading a spanish pdf using PyPDFLoader from langchain the texts do not show in the print special characters like accents or ñ.

Is there a way to use the library to get the text correctly?

```
 loader = PyPDFLoader("IBMwiki.pdf")
    pages = loader.load()
    total_pages = len(pages)

    if end_page is None:
        end_page = len(pages)

    text_list = []
    for i in range(start_page-1, end_page):
        text = pages[i].page_content
        text = text.replace('\n', ' ')
        text = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', text)
        text_list.append(text)
    print(text_list)
```

result: ['Interna'onal Business Machines Corpora'on (IBM) (NYSE: IBM) es una empresa tecnológica mul;nacional estadounidense con sede en Armonk, Nueva York. IBM fabrica y comercial

correct result: International Business Machines Corporation (IBM) (NYSE: IBM) es una empresa tecnológica multinacional estadounidense con sede en Armonk, Nueva York. IBM fabrica y comercial

Comment: Which version of pypdf do you use? Do you have an example PDF that you can link here? pypdf in its latest version should show all accents just fine.